# Spring With Hibernate Mapping to composite key

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to merge the user Object in hibernate. it throws the following error

> **userid** can not be null.

here **userId** and **widgetId** is composite key.
i can save and fetch the same object.
but can not merge.

```
public class User extends BaseModel {

private Long _userId;

private String _name;

private UserOTPMobile _userOTPMobile;

private List<UserWidgetPreference> widgetPreference;
```

Here userWidgetPreference contains the following

```
public class UserWidgetPreference extends BaseModel {

private UserWidgetPreferenceId id = new UserWidgetPreferenceId();
private String position;
```

user widgetpreferenceId comtains

```
public class UserWidgetPreferenceId extends BaseModel {

private User user;
private Widget widget;
```

Mapping in user

```
<bag name="widgetPreference" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false">
        <key>
            <column name="USER_ID"/>                
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.zirius.zerp.core.dao.model.UserWidgetPreference"/>
    </bag>
```

UserWidgetPreference mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.zirius.zerp.core.dao.model.UserWidgetPreference" table="USER_WIDGET_PREFERENCE" >
<composite-id name="id" class="com.zirius.zerp.core.dao.model.UserWidgetPreferenceId">
    <key-many-to-one name="user" class="com.zirius.zerp.core.dao.model.User" column="USER_ID"/>
    <!-- <key-property name="user" type="long" column="USER_ID" /> -->
    <key-many-to-one name="widget" class="com.zirius.zerp.core.dao.model.Widget" column="WIDGET_ID" lazy="false" />
</composite-id>
<property name="position" type="string" column="POSITION" />
```